# Crear un arreglo manual en una variable para luego rellenar un select

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas tardes es posible creo un arreglo en una variable dentro del controlador de Laravel, para luego en la vista rellenar con una iteración un select, con su value y el name??

Estoy probando así pero lo mio no son los arreglos, no los comprendo bien:

```
$selecciones = ['users' => 
                   ['value' => 'hifu-portatil', 'name' => 'Hifu portatil']
               ];
```

Es posible lo que pido??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí es posible, en general, los arreglos pueden recorrerse en las vistas y pueden ser llenados desde una base de datos o en este caso, como lo estas haciendo.

Para poder llenar el select en la vista debes primero asegurarte de haber enviado la variable a tu vista.

```
$selecciones = ['users' => 
    ['value' => 'hifu-portatil', 'name' => 'Hifu portatil'],
    ['value' => 'hifu-portatil2', 'name' => 'Hifu portatil2'],
    ['value' => 'hifu-portatil3', 'name' => 'Hifu portatil3'],
];
return view('tuVista', compact('selecciones'));
```

Ya en la vista solo debes hacer un `foreach`

```
<select name="selecciones " id="selecciones -select">
    @foreach ($selecciones as $item)
    <option value="{{ $item['value'] }}">{{ $item['name'] }}</option>    
    @endforeach    
</select>
```

De esta manera recorreras todo tu arreglo por la clave 'selecciones', donde por cada iteración vas a agregar al select el valor de 'value' y 'name'.

Comment: Muchas gracias @RedSalas , funciona perfectamente. Al menos no iba desencaminado